# get data copied from an excel file in the application in a form of a string array

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

what I'am trying to do is to copy a column from excel, paste the data to the application and then form an array of that data.

I have no idea how to do this I tried this :

```
var x = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
```

but it appears that x is equal to null.
So, Is this possible or is there any alternative way to do this?
And thanks for your help,

Comment: Show us the code that saves to the clipboard.

Comment: Iam sorry the idea was not so clear. What I meant is that the user just copies from an excel file and paste it to the app I didn't write any code to copy to the clipboard

Comment: the GetText method returns an empty string What I want is to get the data that I copied from an excel file in a form of a string array or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting a column and using `GetText()` returned all values in a string delimited by the new line:

> "\r\nTest 1\r\n\r\n\r\nTest 2\r\n\r\nTest 3\r\n"

You can take that value, and split on the new line (removing empty cells with no value):

```
var columnText = Clipboard.GetText();

var values =
  columnText.Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

You'll end up with a string array with (using my example) three elements in it.

Comment: I was testing on a console application it appears that that was the problem when I tried with wpf it worked. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can also get it as Comma Separated Values, like this:

```
var clipObj = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
if (clipObj != null && clipObj.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue))
{
    var csv = clipObj.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue) as string;
    csv.Dump();
}
```